# Not able to form xpath using mule expression for given xml

Tags: xml, xpath, mule, xslt-2.0, esb

Am trying to read data from xml using an expression in **mule** but am getting the following exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: org.mule.api.MuleRuntimeException: Failed to evaluate XPath expression: "//*[xpath:local-name()="oa:ID"]/text()"

**The flow is given below**

```
<flow name="testauditFlow1" doc:name="testauditFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way"
            host="localhost" port="8086" path="test" doc:name="HTTP"/>
            doc:name="DOM to XML" />
        <expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[#[xpath('//*[xpath:local-name()="ID"]/text()').text]]]></expression-component>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
    </flow>
```

**The xml i used is given below**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <_ord:ProcessOrder releaseID="9.0" versionID="7.0.0.0" xmlns:_ord="http://www.test.com/xmlns/test" xmlns:_wcf="http://www.test.com/xmlns/test/9" xmlns:oa="http://www.test.com/xmlns/test/foundation">
         <oa:ApplicationArea xsi:type="_wcf:ApplicationAreaType">
            <oa:CreationDateTime>2012-08-07T13:25:01.337Z</oa:CreationDateTime>
            <oa:ID>1234566</oa:ID>
            <_wcf:BusinessContext/>
         </oa:ApplicationArea>
      </_ord:ProcessOrder>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Why are you using the `xpath:` prefix on the `local-name()` function?  Does it work if you remove the prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I am able to extract the value using XPATH ... You can do it 2 ways :-

1) First way is using **local-name** and without **namespace** :-

```
<logger message="Value of id : #[xpath://.[xpath:local-name()='ID']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

It works perfect and it is simple, but the XPATH is an old way which may be depreciated in Mule

2) The second way and most effective way is using **mulexml:namespace-manager** as following :-
First you use a **mulexml:namespace-manager** in the Mule config before the flow:-

```
<mulexml:namespace-manager includeConfigNamespaces="false">
    <mulexml:namespace prefix="soapenv" uri="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
    <mulexml:namespace prefix="xsi" uri="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
    <mulexml:namespace prefix="soapenc" uri="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
    <mulexml:namespace prefix="xsd" uri="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
    <mulexml:namespace prefix="_ord" uri="http://www.test.com/xmlns/test"/>
    <mulexml:namespace prefix="_wcf" uri="http://www.test.com/xmlns/test/9"/>
    <mulexml:namespace prefix="oa" uri="http://www.test.com/xmlns/test/foundation"/>
</mulexml:namespace-manager>
```

Then use the following XPATH to retrieve the value as I have done it in a logger:-

```
<logger message="Value of id : #[xpath('//_ord:ProcessOrder/oa:ApplicationArea/oa:ID/text()').text]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

So, Both the way you can exact the value and both are working perfect

Comment: Hi it works normally without a cxf component  but if I use a CXF component and a wsdl in it these xpaths not working can u provide any solution for that .Thanks in advance

Comment: But in your flow there was no CXF component mentioned ... So the solution is as per the flow given... Could you pls accept the answer and close this question... Pls open a new question with CXF component in your flow and we will look into it

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you need `xpath:` inside this expression?

```
<expression-component doc:name="Expression">#[xpath('//*[local-name()="ID"]/text()')]</expression-component>
```

According to [this page](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+MEL), there is no need to prefix the `local-name()` function. Also, I'm not sure why you put the whole into a CDATA section.

Comment: I don't need it in c data I tested it with variable it didn't help so I tried with cdata can u pls help me